# Button Transparency when touched

Tags: android, button, widget

**What i have:** I have a calculator layout, with many buttons. And each button has two images.
**One for Pressed state , 
Second for Pressed Released State**
These images work accordingly when the button is pressed and released but these all graphics has made my widget size big.

**What i want:**  i want to used only one image for the button and then apply a alpha (Transparency) on the pressed button in such a way that when it is pressed, it grows some dark in color. In this way i can used less graphics for my widget and size will automatically decrease.
I want to implement all this in a XML file..either as a style or etc.

Plz explain with some example.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [android built-in color transparent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html#transparent):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_pressed="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_button_image" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I have already tried it Yorkw, it fully make the button disappear when pressed...
I actually want to give a slight touch effect (Gradient) when pressed.